# Inter-PAN transmission possibilities with XBee modules

Tags: xbee, zigbee

I'm trying to create a working ZigBee Light Link device using common XBee modules. Now I've ran into a problem where Digi the creators of the XBee modules can't help me either.

I'm trying to find out if it's possible or not to use inter-PAN transmission with these modules. And if so how?

Comment: What is "inter-PAN transmission"

Comment: I think he means from one PAN ID to a different PAN ID, which XBees are not supposed to do (the whole point of separte PANs). Which would be intra-PAN I think.

Comment: Inter PAN transmission was added as an optional function within the smart energy profile. This makes it possible to send a direct single hop packet to a device with a different PAN ID. This is possible if a stub APS is implemented. Although I can't find anything about the stub APS, with XBee modules. I also alreaddy had contact with digi and they didn't even know about it.

Comment: I found out that it apparently is possible with these modules, but the current firmware doesn't support it. So or I would have to ask if Ember ( the maker of the stack ) could implement that for me. Or I would have to find a way to obtain the source code of this firmware myself.